# Как найти координаты углов повернутого прямоугольника?

Tags: математика, геометрия

Зная координаты центра, ширину, длину, угол поворот прямоугольника. Как теперь найти координаты всех углов повернутого прямоугольника?

Comment: Взять учебник по геометрии... Сначала записать координаты неповернутого прямоугольника в начале координат, потом - повернуть, потом - выполнить параллельный перенос...

Comment: Вспомнить школьную геометрию и тригонометрию? Покажите ваши попытки

Comment: проблема в следующем.
Есть игра gta vice city.
Там система координат представлена тремя осями x,y,z.
Автомобили это прямые параллелепипеды.
Мы знаем длину, ширину и высоту авто, также координаты его центра и угол положение авто.
Также мы знаем всё вышеперечисленное у другого авто.
Нам необходимо вычислить координаты всех углов этих 2 параллелепипедов ( авто).
Как определить было ли столкновения двух авто или нет?
Нужны 2 формулы.
Нахождения координат всех 8 углов параллелепипедов.
Проверка касаются 2 прямых параллелепипеда друг друга?

Comment: Забудьте слово "прямые" рядом с прямоугольником и параллелепипедом - они не бывают "кривыми"! Вот что бывает в разработке игр, так это Axis-Aligned - то есть ориентированные параллельно координатным осям. )

Answer (score 5):

Не понятно, что такое "длина" - обычно у прямоугольника выделяют ширину и высоту. Для них и отвечаю...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое за Ваш ответ. значит так. luangle_x = (width/2)*math.cos(angle)-(length/2)*math.sin(angle) + x
luangle_y = (width/2)*math.sin(angle)+(Length/2)*math.cos(angle)+y                          
x и y координаты центра. сейчас находим левый верхний угол?